# Solving 2-CNF TQBF with #SAT solver?

Tags: algorithms, reductions

We clearly know that 2-QCNF is in $\mathsf{P}$. Since that, if I understand it right, it is possible to solve it with #SAT solver (because $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{\#P}$). But how can we only knowing amount of positive assignments for some non-quantified formulae solve 2-QCNF? And why this doesn't hold (at least, assumed so) for general case of TQBF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is a bit misleading to say that $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{\#P}$, since $\mathsf{P}$ is a class of decision problems, while $\mathsf{\#P}$ is a class of counting problems. However, we can think of a decision problem as a counting problem in which the answer is 0 (no) or 1 (yes), and in that sense it is certainly true that $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \mathsf{\#P}$.

The problem $\mathsf{\#SAT}$ is $\mathsf{\#P}$-complete. This means that for any problem $A \in \mathsf{\#P}$ there exists a polynomial time reduction $f$ such that for any instance $x$ of $A$, we have
$$ A(x) = \mathsf{\#SAT}(f(x)), $$
where $A(x)$ is the value of the counting problem $A$ on instance $x$.

Since $\mathsf{2QCNF} \in \mathsf{P}$, there is a trivial reduction from $\mathsf{2QCNF}$ to $\mathsf{\#SAT}$: if the $\mathsf{2QSAT}$ is satisfiable, we output the formula $x$, and otherwise we output the formula $x \land \lnot x$. This reduction runs in polynomial time since $\mathsf{2QCNF} \in \mathsf{P}$.

Comment: But here we solve 2QSAT to convert it to #SAT? Why we even reduce it, if we already know the answer? I thought that's not how reduction works.

Comment: We can do whatever we want as long as we follow the rules. The reduction I describe satisfies all the requisite properties, so it's a valid reduction.

Comment: As to *why* we reduce it, if we already know the answer - it's because *you* asked for such a reduction.

Comment: But if we had $\mathsf{NL}^{\mathsf{\#P}}$ machine, that machine should be capable to solve 2QCNF (or not?) but such reduction is restricted. All I know that such machine can solve 2QCNF with zero-error probability, as well as $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{\#P}}$ machine can solve TQBF with zero-error probability.